# How do I display a clicked button's text on another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I was asked to do a multi-task website in Visual Studio 2010 and I never used it.

And now I'm here challenging me to do it perfectly.

I need a label on a page which will display the text of a button the user clicked on on the previous page, so the person who's using the multi-task site knows he clicked on himself.

My problem is how to connect the button text and label text together.

Here is the HTML (buttons) part:

```
<td colspan="3" style="height: 70%;" valign="top">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Operário 1" Width="12.5%" 
        Height="60px" onclick="Button2_Click" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Operário 2" Width="12.5%" 
        Height="60px" onclick="Button2_Click" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Operário 3" Width="12.5%" 
        Height="60px" onclick="Button2_Click" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Operário 4" Width="12.5%" 
        Height="60px" onclick="Button2_Click" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Operário 5" Width="12.5%" 
        Height="60px" onclick="Button2_Click" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Operário 6" Width="12.5%" 
        Height="60px" onclick="Button2_Click" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" Text="Operário 7" Width="12.5%" 
        Height="60px" onclick="Button2_Click" BorderWidth="0px" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" Text="+" Width="12.5%" 
        Height="60px" onclick="Button1_Click" BorderWidth="0px" />
</td>
```

The aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class operario : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int i=0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Button1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("maquina.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: You definitely need to have a better title than this !!

Comment: I now need to know how to connect that label to the other pages and how to use all buttons to do the same instead of writing one by one.

Comment: Well, you can start making your perfect site from clarifying your question and format it perfectly. Right now your question is hard to understand and hard to read due to bad formatting.

Comment: @humptydumpty I know, first time using this website and I'm a designer I dont know how to describe the thing I want to do x)

Comment: It's a confusing question, but it sounds like the ASP.Net Wizard control could be used [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5%28v=vs.140%29.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7dyf6b5%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: @markpsmith I know it sounds confusing, it is really, I'm new to ASP.NET programming

Comment: What does a "multi task website" mean? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you give an example what these "tasks" are?

Comment: @kha This thing I'm doing it's for a factory, they will have a touch screen to select the worker (the one who's operating on the screen) then they will have a page with the machines in the factory, basicly what I want is to appear on the second page their name which is on a button they press to select the worker. Don't know if I made me clear enough

Comment: Hi Hugo. I've taken a stab at cleaning up your question. It sounds like you want to present the user with a page that has a button for each operator of the site. When the operator clicks on their button you want to display that text (Operário 3, for example) on the next page, correct?

Comment: @jamesSkemp first of all thank you and yes that is correct, I placed another question similar to this one but with another problem and they sujested to use session variables.

Comment: See it. I might recommend deleting this question if you can, otherwise a mod probably will (someone already flagged it which is why I even saw it). http://stackoverflow.com/q/28632088/11912 seems to be exactly what you were looking for and has a good answer (I seconded the Session variable answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a lable on each page to do the same? Use MasterPage. http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_masterpages.asp

Comment: Yea that kinda works, now I just need to know how I connect the label from the "button_click" to appear on the label the Text on the button.