# Is there some way to go on the previous page get the pressed button text?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on Visual Studio, in C# language

I would like to ask if there's someway to go back to get the ButtonX.Text I pressed on the previous page, some sort of Login without a password.

Basically I need a worker to specify which person he is by clicking on their name (button) then it goes foward to the next page I have a label on the MasterPage but it resets everytime it goes on a next page what I would like to do is keep the info there

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtgqD.jpg]

If you need some code tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Go with @Zollistic's answer. It's correct for Your needs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based-off your reply to Zollistic's answer, you could do this...

Apply this event to all your all your worker buttons...

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Worker"] == null) Session["Worker"] = "";
    Session["Worker"] += button.Text + ",";
}
```

Now Session["Worker"] has a character-delimited list of all the clicked buttons. The character in this example is a comma; but you can change it to whatever you want (i.e. a pipe "|").

Answer (score 1):

You could use session variables?

On the button click handler on the first page...

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Worker"] = button.Text;
}
```

Then on the second page...

```
Label.Text = Session["Worker"];
```

Comment: Is it someway to cover all buttons text, or I have to do one by one? 'Cause this is for a lot of factories and some have 100 workers others less and so on...

Comment: You should be able to cast the sender as a button and get the text. `Button b = (Button) sender; Session["Worker"] = b.Text;` Then in your button `onclick` point them all to this. Note that you may want to look at dynamically adding the buttons to the page, if you really have that many workers.

Comment: one question, where do I use the `Label.Text = Session["Worker"];`? Is it on the .aspx.cs file? I'm new to this program